# Cypress on click, is there any method to wait until DOM is loaded? (without using wait())

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, cypress

I have a small problem in React project, when I want to use `.click()` from Cypress sometimes I have an error **failed because this element is detached from the dom.** The simple solution is to add `wait()` before each test to let the site render fully but it isn't the best solution for me. Is there any way to do it without using `wait()`?

Comment: What does your test look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to a known cypress issue that they promise to fix soon: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7306

Until that's solved you can either add `.wait()`, if it works for your scenario, or alternative try `.click({force: true})`. Either have downsides though.

Comment: The issue you cited is an edge-case where the `<select>` has an event handler that performs a form submit. This question looks like a React re-render after some data has been fetched.

Comment: The issue just gives `<select>` as a reproducible example, but it's a general problem, and if you check the comments the problem of react re-render is just a subproblem and is recognized as a part of it.

In general, that problem is [2nd most-commented issue currently open for cypress](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Acomments-desc). Many people will be happy when it's finally fixed, including anyone using reactjs.

Answer (score 1):

Cypress docs are your friend =)

I found this [blog](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/22/when-can-the-test-click/#try-and-try-again) on docs. It details using [`cypress-pipe`](https://github.com/NicholasBoll/cypress-pipe#readme) to have a callback function before the assertion

```js
// create a click function as pipe does not take any cypress commands
const click = $el => $el.click()

cy.get('.your-element')
  .should('be.visible')
  .pipe(click)
  .should($el => {
    // whatever assertion you need after your click event is attached
  })

// calendar should close on the user click
cy.get('.owl-dt-popup').should('not.be.visible')
```

Comment: Why are you using pipe here? How does it overcome the error?

Comment: Basically, with the `.pipe()` followed `.should()` will guarantee the click function will be retried until the assertion passes or times out.

Comment: I can see it's useful when the attaching of click handler is slow, but how would it fix "detached from DOM" error is the real question. I think you need to re-query `.your-element` within the pipe in order to pick up the new version of the  element that replaces the detached version.

Answer (score 0):

How about you write an `should('be.visible')` assertion before clicking the button. Something like:

```js
cy.get('button').should('be.visible').click()
```

Comment: I tested it with ```.should('be.visible')``` problem is that it's visible but not attached to the DOM events. So ```.should('be.visible')``` is true but clicking is not making any action.